Springboot customizing login page breaks logout
When I try to use a custom login page in my Springboot application the /logout page breaks.
I enable the custom page by adding this to my configuration:
.formLogin((formLogin) -> formLogin
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
)

The error I get is

org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource logout.

Removing .loginPage("/login") gives me back the default login page and logging in and out then works. From what I can find in the Spring documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html) this setting should not change the logout behavior. Can anyone tell me how I can have the logout functionality unaffected, but still customize the login page (or is this not possible and should I give up trying...)?
Full config:
package com.myapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyAppSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/webjars/**", "/css/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((formLogin) -> formLogin
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((formLogout) -> formLogout.permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/"));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}


1.: Providing only a small snippet of the relevant code (in your case the SecurityFilterChain) is never a good idea. 2.: Have you also set up HttpSecurity#logoout?

@Slevin thank you, edited the question with the full Config file. I tried both with and without configuring logout, neither works.
